# How to search in JSON and return search results in activity

Tags: android, json

I am parsing a `JSON` in my activity to display both text and images in a `gridView`.However i would like to try to add **search functionality** on this `JSON` and display the results on the activity.

**For example consider a** `JSON` **script on an online server like this:**

```js
[
    {
        "title": "Ongata Rongai",
        "image": "http://snapt.t15.org/melanie/real_estates/images/house1.jpg",
        "rating": 5 500 000,
        "releaseYear": 2014,
        "genre": ["Spacious open lounge and kitchen"]
    },
 {
        "title": "Kisumu",
        "image": "http://snapt.t15.org/melanie/real_estates/images/house2.jpg",
        "rating": 1 700 000,
        "releaseYear": 2014,
        "genre": ["high end townhouse."]
    },
 {
        "title": "Mombasa",
        "image": "http://snapt.t15.org/melanie/real_estates/images/house3.jpg",
        "rating": 68 000,
        "releaseYear": 2014,
        "genre": ["Its fully fitted kitchedn pantry with a beautyful backyard."]
    }
  ]
```

I would like to implement search of **title** like **Kisumu** and the result to be displayed will be from this part only so that i parse this alone:

```js
[
 {
        "title": "Kisumu",
        "image": "http://snapt.t15.org/melanie/real_estates/images/house2.jpg",
        "rating": 1 700 000,
        "releaseYear": 2014,
        "genre": ["high end townhouse."]
    }
  ]
```

Is there a way of achieving the above?

I am open to ideas and suggestions and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do u mean : u want to search from the data coming from server ? or based on your input you want to get filtered results from server ?

Comment: @Atmaram either way sounds fine,jus the one with the simplest workable neat solution

Answer (score 2):

You can't search json directly. Convert the json to `List` Java classes. Then use Java API like `Predicate` to find necessary java class that satisfy your condition. For **eg:** Title as **Kusumu** as you asked.

Which will limit the list of classes to one that satisfy the condition. Then convert the java class back to json if you need Json.

Note: You can use `GSON` for easy `class <-> json` conversion

**UPDATE**

For converting Json to Java classes

`List<ModelClass> models = new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonString, ModelClass.java);`

Then using predicate

> ```
> public static Predicate<ModelClass> isHavingTitle() {
>     return p -> p.getTitle().contains("Kusumu");
> }
> ```

In Java 8 predicate filtering can be done like below in other case you can just google it. This is a sample

```
public static List<ModelClass> filterEmployees (List< ModelClass > models, Predicate< ModelClass > predicate) {
    return models.stream().filter( predicate ).collect(Collectors.<ModelClass>toList());
}
```

I didn't compile any of this :)

```
String filteredJson = new Gson().toJson(models);
```

Comment: Is there a working example you can point me to?I am totally a newbie to this.

Comment: Thank you,let me try this and i will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

this method give resualt of server and title as you want and returns search result as JSONObject

```
private JSONObject SearchMethod(String result,String Key)
{

//result is your server response 
//Key is Kisumu 
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);

    for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){                        
        JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
        if(e.c.getString("title").contains(Key))
            return e ;     
        }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I am curious as to where exactly i put this..Lets say i have an activity with an editText and search button..How do i implement this method?

Comment: this method must be work for JSON string and parse that to json objects

Comment: use this method in  onPostExecute (if use asynctaks class for call your webservice )
give result from server ( result is json string ) 
and call method
SearchMethod(result,YourEditText.GetText());

Comment: check this out : 

http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-json-web-service-tutorial/

http://mobiforge.com/design-development/consuming-json-services-android-apps